# plotting matplotlib from nump ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

This is embarrassing, but I am unable to plot this:

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  datf=np.loadtxt(filename, dtype=float,delimiter=" ")
  print((datf))
  plt.plot(datf[:0], datf[:1])
  plt.show()
```

This is `datf`:

```
[[  1.         19.778986 ]
 [  1.3625678  -1.9363698]
 [  1.4142136   6.5144132]
 [  1.6901453   3.8092139]
 [  2.         -4.0222051]]
```

And the error is:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to plot the first column as x and the second column as y. You made a mistake in indexing. To get the first column of datf, you need to do `datf[:, 0]` (note the comma).

Your final code will look like:

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  datf=np.loadtxt(filename, dtype=float,delimiter=" ")
  print((datf))
  plt.plot(datf[:, 0], datf[:, 1])  # note the commas here
  plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed that, and had no clue why this trivial thing is not working

Answer (score 0):

to get the 1st and 2nd column, indexing must be

```
plt.plot(datf[:,0],datf[:,1])
```